# Fill values in a column of a particular row with the value of same column from another row based on a condition on second column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe which represents a retail chain data set. It has columns Item_Identifier, Item_Weight, Item_MRP, Outlet_Identifier. The column Item_Weight which represents the weight of the particular item in gms, and is numeric, has certain missing values. The column Item_Weight has missing values for Items where the column Outlet_Identifier = OUT019 or OUT027. Though, the same Item (identified by Item_Identifier) in a different row with another Outlet_Identifier (other than OUT019 or OUT027) has Item_Weight present and can be used to substitute the missing Item_Weight for Outlet_Identifier (OUT019 or OUT027).

I have written the following code but it seems to have a problem. And laso it is not the cleanest way to do:

```
items = df_train[df_train.Outlet_Identifier == "OUT019"]['Item_Identifier']
listItems = []
for i in items:
    u = df_train.query('(Item_Identifier == @i) & (Outlet_Identifier != 
         "OUT019") & (Outlet_Identifier != "OUT027")').head(1)
    if not u.empty:
        listItems.append(u.at[u.index[0],'Item_Weight'])

df_rep = pd.concat([items.reset_index(),pd.DataFrame(listItems)],axis=1)
df_rep.columns = ['row', 'Item_Identifier', 'Item_Weight']
for index, row in df_rep.iterrows():
    df_train.loc[df_train.Item_Identifier == row.Item_Identifier ]
                                      ['Item_Weight']= row['Item_Weight']
```

Need some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['Item_Weight'] = df.groupby(['Item_Identifier','Outlet_Identifier'])['Item_Weight'].ffill()
df['Item_Weight'] = df.groupby(['Item_Identifier','Outlet_Identifier'])['Item_Weight'].bfill()
```

This should solve your problem. The `ffill()` will look at all the next rows to see if you have anything available and will fill it and `bfill()` will look at previous rows to fill the null values.

Comment: Thank you. Nice thought process, I just had to remove Outlet_Identifier from Group By and it worked perfectly. Appreciate ur help :)